# Set onClick listener on extended Listview

Tags: android, email, android-listview

> I am working on Email application. I am able to get Inbox Mail in
>   listview. Now I have to click the list and open that particular email
>   in different activity. But I don't understand  how to set Onclick in
>   listview.
>
> Here is my code of inbox-mail activity.

```
  public class InboxActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public static String uid;
    public static String uri;
    SharedPreferences myPriferene2;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inboxList;

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray inbox = null;

    // Inbox JSON url
    private static final String INBOX_URL = "http://xyz/webservice/inboxlist.php";

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGES = "messages";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_FROM = "from";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
    //private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox_list);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



        myPriferene2=getSharedPreferences("my_key_share", MODE_PRIVATE);

        uri = myPriferene2.getString("uid","");


        String uid =uri.toString();

        Log.d("helloooooo",uid);
        // Loading INBOX in Background Thread
        new LoadInbox().execute(uid);
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all INBOX messages by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadInbox extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InboxActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Inbox ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Inbox JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", args[0]));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

            try {
                inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
                // looping through All messages
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String from = c.getString(TAG_FROM);
                    String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                    //String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                    //map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    inboxList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            InboxActivity.this, inboxList,
                            //R.layout.inbox_list_item, new String[] { TAG_FROM, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DATE },
                            R.layout.inbox_list_item, new String[] { TAG_FROM, TAG_SUBJECT,TAG_ID},
                            //new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.emailID});

                    new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject , R.id.date});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

> here is my ListActivity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> this is my list item activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#746555"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/from"/>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="8dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Mr. negative marker. please read the question carefully, then press negative button. and before that. please answer my question otherwise stop using stack-overflow.

Comment: Where is your ListView??

Comment: @Sajal now check my edited question.. and if still dont understand where is my ListView so plz dont even try this.

Comment: have you tried using [onListItemClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)?

Comment: sorry devraj, I still can't see any declaration of your ListView in your java code but still you can set item click by using `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {});`

Comment: @bharat please chk the code.. and tell me where I have to put onclick

Comment: @Sajal he is extending `ListActivity` so dont need listview instance visit [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Thanx bharat. got it now. @devraj just override onListItemClick

Comment: @bharat thanx bharat for telling him... He marked my question negetive just becoz he didnt find listview declaration.. :P

Comment: @devraj hahhaha .I didnt marked your question negative.

Comment: @Sajal lolzz.. no prob bro.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in my app. First you have to get the ListView and set an onClickListener. Then you get the "id" for the item selected and launch a new class to view the content for that selected id.

```
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
```

Place that under your onCreate method. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Here's the complete code:

```
    public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "your_url_here";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: @Devraj if you would like to see the entire code, I can provide that as well. Cheers!

Comment: Thanx Steve for your kind help. But here I am not declaring Listview because I am extending it. now plz tell me according to my code, how can I set onclick.

Comment: @Devraj Your welcome and I mean no disrespect but I am extending it as well. ;) Check my edit.

Comment: Thnx Steve. :) now I can move from Current activity to next activity. But It shows a blank page. I am only using intent to move to next activity and not parsing any value from here to there. what could be the reason?
second thing is, I have to send the value I am gettting in TAG_ID. can you please tell me how can I do this??

Comment: @Devraj sorry for the late reply. Email me and I'll make sure you get everything working the way you need it to. dev.curtrostudios@gmail.com

Comment: plz chk your mail . thnx you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

just override onListItemClick in your activity.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(InboxActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: sajal, can you please show to code piece according to my code.. would be helpful.